# locking tab bar items and unlocking via login page

Tags: objective-c, uitabbaritem, uitabcontroller

Hey guys having trouble with the UI tab controller,

So I have a login screen as my first controller I was wondering if there is a way to lock tab bar items and then unlocking them after login is successful?

At the moment I'm using `NSDictionary` to store my username and passwords and an `UIAlertView` for alerting whether the login is successful or not, but there really is no point of a login if tabs are accessible without the logging in.

below is my current code for logging in

```
 - (IBAction)loginNow {
    if ([[credentialsDictionary objectForKey:usernameField.text]isEqualToString:passwordField.text]) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Correct" message:@"You have successfully logged in." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        usernameField.hidden = YES;
        passwordField.hidden = YES;
        goButton.hidden = YES;
        welcomeField.hidden = NO;
        nameField.hidden = NO;

    } else {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"You have entered an incorrect Username or Password" message:@"Please try again." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `tabBarController:shouldSelectViewController:` method in `UITabBarControllerDelegate` protocol to return `NO` for tabs which should be inaccessible.

Set the relevant object (probably your main view controller) as the delegate of the tab bar, and implement the above method, returning `NO` when the user is not logged in and tries to access a tab which they should not have access to.